# Why can't I create a generic bubbleSort with generator? (Java)

Tags: java, generics

I've been trying to learn Generics implementation of a sorting class, but I get this error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method compare(T, T) from the type Comparator" (line 14).

Why do I get this message? I haven't declared my sorting class static.

I'm trying to make a sorting class which could be used for any type of class as long as it implements Comparator.

```
public class GenericBSort<T extends Comparator<T>> {

public GenericBSort(T[] arr){
     boolean needNextPass = true;
        for (int k = 1; k < arr.length && needNextPass; k++)
        { // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed
          needNextPass = false;
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - k; i++){  
              if (T.compare(arr[i], arr[i + 1])>0){ // Swap list[i] with list[i + 1]
                  T temp = arr[i];
                  arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                  arr[i + 1] = temp;

                  needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
            }
          }
        }



}
```

}

Thanks a lot! 
(I know it's a newbie question but I really couldn't figure it out and need to understand this : )

Comment: You need an instance of the class.

Comment: T.compare is a static reference. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator works on an object and is not static - so you should obtain two values from the array, call the compare method on the first and pass the second as parameter.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I changed it to:
 if (arr[i].compare(arr[i], arr[i + 1])>0)

But what's the point of using an object to implement the compare of 2 objects (that could have no connection to the object I've implemented the method with)? Is there a way to do it like I wanted to in the first place?

Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You could move the comparison code to a new static method on your Comparator, and call that method from the usual non-static method.

Comment: The idea is, that an object of any given type knows best how to compare itself with other objects (preferably of the same type) - that's why the responsibility lies with the actual object.

Answer (score 2):

T represents a class, so in the line

```
if(T.compare(arr[i], arr[i + 1])>0)
```

you are doing a static method call.

You probably need to change it for

```
if(arr[i].compare(arr[i + 1])>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make a sorting class which could be used for any type of class as long as it implements Comparator.

Well, that's an unusual path.  `Comparator` normally is a separate class from the thing being sorted.

It's sensible to make a sorting class which could be used for any type of class as long as it implements `Comparable`.

You've also put much of the sorting logic in the constructor, which is a bit abnormal as well.  It's usually better to make a separate method that does the work.

A reasonable approach to doing this for the `Comparable` interface would be approximately as follows:

```
public class ComparableSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public ComparableSort() {
    }

    public void sort(T[] arr){
        boolean needNextPass = true;
        for (int k = 1; k < arr.length && needNextPass; k++)
        { // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed
            needNextPass = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - k; i++){
                if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[i + 1])>0){ // Swap list[i] with list[i + 1]
                    T temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;

                    needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] test = new Integer[]{5,3,2,4,1};
        ComparableSort<Integer> sorter = new ComparableSort<Integer>();
        sorter.sort(test);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can sensibly make a sorting class which can be used for any type of class at all with the provision of a `Comparator` for that class:

```
public class ComparatorSort<T> {

    private final Comparator<T> comp;

    public ComparatorSort(Comparator<T> comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    public void sort(T[] arr){
        boolean needNextPass = true;
        for (int k = 1; k < arr.length && needNextPass; k++)
        { // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed
            needNextPass = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - k; i++){
                if (comp.compare(arr[i], arr[i + 1])>0){ // Swap list[i] with list[i + 1]
                    T temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = temp;

                    needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] test = new Integer[]{5,3,2,4,1};
        ComparatorSort<Integer> sorter = new ComparatorSort<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
                if (integer > integer2)
                    return 1;
                else if (integer < integer2)
                    return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        });
        sorter.sort(test);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }
}
```

Of course bubble sort isn't a good sort, and there are better sorts built into Java libraries already, but this is a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

T.compare is a static reference. Can't use that.  You need to compare an instance with another instance.
Plus, doesn't compare take only a single argument?

Comment: Compare takes two arguments.

Comment: I could have simply used compareTo (of comparable, which takes only a single argument) but I wanted to practice the Comparator (with good reason as you can see :

Comment: Yep.. I didn't initially get that the class to be compared is the same as the comparator class.  First time trying to answer something on a tablet.. lesson learned!